# Apache Flink -- daily aggregation of hourly aggregated data

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a windowed hourly aggregated DataStream.

DataStream`<RawData>` ds = .....

```
  SingleOutputStreamOperator<HourlyAggregated> hourly =  
  ds.keyBy(HourlyCountersAggregation.KEY_SELECTOR)
             .timeWindow(Time.hours(1))
             .aggregate(new HourlyCountersAggregation());
```

Every hour this DataStream`<HourlyAggregated>` sinks to Cassandra.

I want also daily aggregation of same DataStream`<HourlyAggregated>`.

What is recommended method to do this from hourly aggregated DataStream in order to avoid keeping a large daily state of streaming from DataStream`<RawData>` ds ....

Answer (score 1):

I think you might try forking the job graph so that you use the output of the hourly aggregated data both in a sink and in the next window (so that you can make the daily aggregation on top of the hourly aggregation, saving computation time). Something like:

```
SingleOutputStreamOperator<HourlyAggregated> hourly = ds.keyBy(HourlyCountersAggregation.KEY_SELECTOR)
         .timeWindow(Time.hours(1))
         .aggregate(new HourlyCountersAggregation());

hourly.addSink(...);

SingleOutputStreamOperator<HourlyAggregated> daily = hourly.timeWindow(Time.hours(24))
         .trigger(CountEventTrigger.of(24))
         .aggregate(...);
```

Comment: This only works if the aggregation can be partially done (chances are good since you are using aggregate). Note, you're not saving on state (`aggregate` holds a single accumulator per window) but save computations, because the daily window aggregates only 24 records.

Comment: You're (obviously) right @FabianHueske, I have edited the answer to remote the "saving on state" part.